# interal error with querybuilder of cakephp on Prod

Tags: php, cakephp, wamp, cakephp-3.0

I'm working under wamp with php 7.4.26 @windows.
I have a project under cakephp. It works well on Dev Environnement.

However when I upload the code on PROD (linux/ PHP 7.4), it gives me an internal error (500). I know what's wrong, but I don't know why this happens only on linux.

```
$users = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('users');
$user = $users->find('all')->contain(['Products' => ['sort' => ['Products.id' => 'DESC']]])->first();

SELECT 
products.id AS `products__id`, 
products.name AS `products__name`

FROM products products 
ORDER BY Products.id DESC -- Products vs products!!
```

The problem is that the "P" in Product is capitalized in the "sort". So to solve the problem I have to do this: `['sort' => ['products.id' => 'DESC']]`

Question is: how to make it so that there is no check on the case (like with windows@WAMP)

Comment: Windows is Case InSensitive, Linux/Unix is Case Sensitive. Standard practice is to make everything that could possibly be affected by this difference lower case. However in windows if you code the table name with a Capital `P`  it does not case (case insensitive) but Linux does care

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59407/how-to-make-mysql-table-name-case-insensitive-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This seems not to be php related, but more likely coming from the SQL engine you use which is different under the WAMP context and the linux server.
WAMP lets the user choose between MariaDB and MySQL, and it seems you don't mention which database engine is used on the linux side.

The fact is that either MySQL or MariaDB are said, according to a quick search, to be case insensitive on table names by default.
So, i think you should at first glance try to get the information about which SQL engine is used on the linux server, and then try to change the collation used for storing the table names. If you cannot change it, you will have to adapt your code to it.

But at last, since relying on case sensitivity can be source of errors, relying on case insensitivity can also be source of errors, at your place I would avoid both.

See this post about collation on an SQL server :
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163808/sql-server-on-linux-case-sensitivity